# Eclipse CDT doesn't use my Makefile when I try to build.

Tags: c, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have some source code with a Makefile that builds just fine from the command line.

I followed the eclipse CDT instructions for importing a project with existing sources.

I opened the make file, and saw all the makefile targets in the Outline view.

I right clicked on one, and added it to the "Make Target" tab.

I double clicked it, and the console said it couldn't find that target:

```
14:24:13 **** Build of configuration Debug for project xxxxxxxxxx ****
make build-modules 
make: *** No rule to make target `build-modules'.  Stop.
```

Go back to the command line and type "make build-modules" and it works fine.

There are no other makefiles in this project.  I do not know why this is failing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a new project in Eclipse.

2) Import just the files that you already have.

3) Click build and make sure that you have clicked inside an open file of the project, that is open in the editor view.

User had to do also:

"Import project from Makefile" and that got my targets working.

Comment: this worked.  ACtually, I used "Import project from Makefile" and that got my targets working.  Question:  How do you set include search paths?

Comment: Go to your project on the left side of Eclipse and hit right click. Then properties and then Properties to see what's available. However, I think that what you are looking is under the project folder, in includes. I will edit my answer with your result. @marathon a better answer to your question is here: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm